# TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (32, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (224, 224, 3) was expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, tensorflow-datasets

My generator code has takes dataframe(csv file) and images as input and generates images with label.
My generator code is:

```
class ImageSequence:
    def __init__(self, df, mode,img_size=(224, 224), num_channels=3):
        self.df = df
        self.indices = np.arange(len(df))
        self.batch_size = 32
        self.img_dir = 'dataset'
        self.img_size = tuple(img_size)
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.mode = mode
        
        
     def __getitem__(self, idx):
         sample_indices = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
         imgs = []
         genders = []
         ages = []
         for _, row in self.df.iloc[sample_indices].iterrows():
             img = cv2.imread(str(os.path.join(self.img_dir, row["img_paths"])))
             img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
             img = cv2.resize(img,  self.img_size)
             img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
            
             imgs.append(img)
             genders.append(row["genders"])
             ages.append(row["ages"])

         return imgs, genders
      
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    
    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(self.__len__()):
            yield self.__getitem__(i)
            
            if i == self.__len__()-1:
                self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
```

And using the below code to call the generator to train the model

```
epochs = 20
batch_size = 32

csv_path = 'asian_dataset.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(str(csv_path))
train, val = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, test_size=0.1)

train_gen = ImageSequence(train, "train")
val_gen = ImageSequence(val, "val")

print(train_gen)

ot = (tf.float32, tf.int32)
os = ((224, 224, 3), ())
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(train_gen,output_types=ot,output_shapes=os)
val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(val_gen,output_types=ot,output_shapes=os)
print(train_data)

train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)
val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size)

print(train_data)
```

the above code when executes has error

> TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (32, 224, 224, 3)
> where an element of shape (224, 224, 3) was expected .

I haven't used `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` earlier, but due to lack of memory of the system I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very easy to understand. when the `ImageSequence` is called it creates a dataset with batch size 32. So changing the `os` variable to `((batch_size, 224, 224, 3), ())` should just work fine. In your case `batch_size = 32`. If you have memory issue then just decrease the `batch_size = 8` or less then 8.

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 32, 224, 224, 3). it generates this error if i make those changes. I am using using resnet50 model to train it

Comment: Can you give me a dummy sample of the original dataset so that I can generate the error?

Comment: https://github.com/yu4u/age-gender-estimation, used this github link and created dataset using create_db_utkface.py and using UTKFace dataset. You can also check the src/generator.py code i have modified it to use as generator

Comment: I am unable to generate the error. It is working fine on my side. As you are using resNet50, you don't need to include the **batch_size** as the first dimension of the data. Can you not divide the dataset into batches and try it again?

Comment: yes I am using resnet50 as resnet152 is very heavy on my system. and using tensorflow 2.11

Comment: how to divide the dataset in batches and use it. like train on batch 32 and validation on batch 64 ?

Comment: This is actually not possible. You have to keep both the batch size same.

Comment: okay I have kept both the batch size =32, still it has the error